# Optional Char in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as below:-

```
<option id="ps_account_type_opt_1" value="1" selected="">[ Active Directory ]</option>\n<option id="ps_account_type_opt_2" value="2">Local</option>
```

I was trying to get "value" from the above string using a generic regular expression similar to below one.

VARIABLE = [ Active Directory ]

or

VARIABLE = Local

or

VARIABLE = Active Directory

```
<option(.*)value="(\d+)"(.*)>VARIABLE</option>
```

The problem is i need to change my VARIABLE from [ Active Directory ] to \[ Active Directory \]. What should i change in regular expression so that "[" and "]" becomes optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<option[^>]+>\[?(?<VARIABLE>.+?)\]?<\/option>
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/SonFgU/3

Answer (score 0):

Put a `?` after each character or group that you require to be optional.

Example: `abc?` will match both `abc` and `ab`, because the `c?` is optional.